# change function call sequence based on a request parameter

Tags: scala

I have a situation similar to below where if request is coming from the UI then request must be validated first before doing anything else. However if request wasn't submitted from the UI - but say via EDI -> in this case there are some biz req how a child data "id" is populated in the request after persisting parent data and use parent data id into child data section. that detail isn't important for this question.

In order to *change order of method calls* inside a `for` comprehension I have something similar to below which looks bit repetitive and non idiomatic . is there a better way to achieve this?

```
def persistData(req : Request) = {
req.actionFromUI match{
  case Some(_) => for{
     validatedReq <- validateRequest(req) //1st thing
     transformedReq <- transformRequest(validatedReq)
     persitedReq <- persistRequestData(transformedReq)
  }
  case None => for{
    transformedReq <- transformRequest(validatedReq)
    persitedReq <- persistRequestData(transformedReq)
    validatedReq <- validateRequest(persitedReq) //last thing
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
def persistData(req : Request) = {
 val (c1, c2, c3) = req.actionFromUI match{
  case Some(_) => (validateRequest(req), 
                   transformRequest(validatedReq),
                   persistRequestData(transformedReq))
  case _ => (transformRequest(validatedReq),
             persistRequestData(transformedReq), 
             validateRequest(persitedReq))
 }
 for {
    f1 <- c1
    f2 <- c2
    f3 <- c3
 } // .. do something here with f1, f2, f3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (assuming your `validateRequest` returns an `Option[Request]`)?

```
val (preValidate, postValidate) = req.actionFromUI match {
   case Some(_) => (validateRequest _,  Option[Request].apply _)
   case _ => (Option[Request].apply _, validateRequest _)
}

for {
   pre <- preValidate(req)
   transformed <- transformRequest(pre)
   persisted <- persistRequest(transformed)
   post <- postValidate(persisted)
}
```

Or alternatively

```
def validateRequest(req: Request, pre: Boolean) = 
  if(req.actionFromUI.isDefined == pre) validateRequest(req) else Some(req)

for {
   pre <- validateRequest(req, true)
   transformed <- transformRequest(pre)
   persisted <- persistRequest(transformed)
   post <- validateRequest(persisted, false)
}
```